# Certificate signed with custom CA in Kubernetes not Valid

Tags: linux, docker, openssl, kubernetes

I am attempting to setup the following process.

1. Pod starts and generates a private key and csr
2. Submits csr to password protected service for signing and ip verification
3. Service returns valid crt that is then packed into a .p12 along with the private key generated in step 1

The setup I'm testing here is that I'm attempting to use this so I can have a grafana instance send webhook to the service which is then routed to SNS (I don't want to use aws lambda as it's a lot of overhead for just a sms message, as well as being able to keep all of my notification webhooks in one place). When attempting to hit the kubernetes service at the following URL

`https://zevrant-notification-service/zevrant-notification-service/webhooks/serviceDown`

I receive the following error from grafana

```
Failed to send alert notifications" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="Post \"https://zevrant-notification-service/zevrant-notification-service/webhooks/serviceDown\": 
x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match zevrant-notification-service" remote_addr=10.32.0.1
```

`

I attempted to make the same request via wget from inside the pod and received a similar error.

```
wget https://zevrant-notification-service/zevrant-notification-service/webhooks/serviceDown

Connecting to zevrant-notification-service (10.105.135.223:443)
ssl_client: zevrant-notification-service: name 'zevrant-notification-service' not present in 
server certificate
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer
```

`

From what I can understand is that it's a problem with the certificate but when I inspect the certificate as such the response contains the correct cname. The certificate also contains the pod ip as a ip SAN

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in test.pem 

subject=C = US, ST = MI, O = Zevrant Services Inc, OU = MyDivision, CN = zevrant-notification-service
```

To me this looks correct so I'm unsure as to what action to take next. Complete certificate details follow (example certificate as these keys are ephemeral and are revoked once the pod is terminated)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: the [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) should include at least the CN. Yours only includes the IP 10.33.0.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there my friend. The SAN must contain both the original CN (zevrant-notification-service) and the alternate name (10.105.135.223)

You currently have 10.105.135.223 as the SAN, which invalidates the original CN (zevrant-notification-service).

Comment: haha of course it was something that simple :)